# Copy single cell value in range if multiple criteria is met

Tags: microsoft-excel, range, if

I am trying to create a map to see who is positioned where. I am quite stumped on this as I cannot get a single output from my attempts and also I have only achieved FALSE and Blank responses.

I want to get B6 to appear next to Seat 01 in H2. The criterias are that it needs to have Seat 1 as Seat and have not departed.And to go through entire range.

I have attempted different IF, IF+AND and IFS combination with no luck. How do I go about doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a formula like this:

```
=INDEX($B$4:$B$10,MATCH(1,(F4=$C$4:$C$10)*($D$4:$D$10=""),0))
```

[image: Seat numbers]

Comment: Thanks this definately worked. And was elegant to implement!